# This element is working on Jenkins previously, but not working now on Selenium Java Cucumber BDD framwork. I am facing this issue consistenly

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

Results :

```
Tests in error: 
  invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression None edit reseller content lib because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'None edit reseller content lib' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.64)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'QA-IZ-01', ip: '172.16.249.52', os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.18'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 113.0.5672.64, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae..., userDataDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\scop...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:57100}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 76235637857a93ecc562d941c03b2d11
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=None edit reseller content lib}
  invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression None edit reseller content lib because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'None edit reseller content lib' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.64)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'QA-IZ-01', ip: '172.16.249.52', os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.18'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 113.0.5672.64, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae..., userDataDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\scop...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:57100}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 76235637857a93ecc562d941c03b2d11
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=None edit reseller content lib}
```

Comment: please, don't ask more than one question with the same topic in a row and have patience.

Comment: Judging by the errors you are receiving, the execution setup you're using now is missing crucial information. Without more information it's not possible to say more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the XPath value being used is "None edit reseller content lib," which is not a valid XPath expression.

**Make Sure XPath is Correct:**
This error coming because the XPath you're using is not right.
You need to go and find the correct XPath from the web page by using Inspect Element in the browser.

**Write Code with Correct XPath:**
Once you got correct XPath, put it in your code like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("put xpath here"));
```

**Wait for Element If Needed:**
You can use WebDriverWait in Selenium to make it wait.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("put xpath here")));
```

**Check if App Changed:**
If this was working before and now not working, maybe something changed in your app.

Note: If still problem is there, see if you can update Selenium or WebDriver. Sometimes old versions not work well with new browsers.